# Inequality of expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Is it true that if $E[X] \leq E[Y]$, then $X \leq Y$ a.e?

My idea of proof: Consider $A=\{Y < X\}$. $\int_{A}Y-X \leq 0$. But, by assumption, $E[X] \leq E[Y]$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$

Comment: Suppose $X=0$ with probability $.99$ and $X=10$ with probability $.01$, and that $Y$ is the constant $1$.  Then $E[X]<E[Y]$ but $X>Y$ with positive probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X$ with standard normal distribution and $Y=2X$ to get a counterexample.

Comment: Does the conclusion hold if $E[X1_{A}] \leq E[Y1_{A}]$ for every A in the sigma-algebra?

Comment: Yes, it does hold. You can use the fact that $E(Y-X)I_A \geq 0$ where $A=\{Y >X\}$.